# How to specify a maven repository for the maven_aar rule?

Tags: bazel

How to specify a maven repository for the `maven_aar` rule? It seems like that the `maven_aar` doesn't recognize my `maven_server`:

```
maven_server(
    name = "default",
    url = "http://xxx"
)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the regular maven constructs and not maven_server.
From this closed issue ([How to specify a maven repository for the maven_aar rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404421/how-to-specify-a-maven-repository-for-the-maven-aar-rule#)):
"... the maven_server rule is just for the native maven_jar rule. We made the skylark maven_jar and mane_aar rules differently. Instead it uses the standard maven settings XML convention.

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

You can either put your repository in the global maven settings file on your machine, or you can create a custom settings.xml and put the path to it in the 'settings' attribute of maven_aar."

Answer (score 0):

The `maven_jar` and `maven_aar` rules in `@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:maven_rules.bzl` read Maven settings from the Maven install settings file `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`, the user install settings file `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` or from a path specified in the `settings` attribute of the `maven_aar` rule.

To specify a repository for your project, you will probably want to write a Maven settings.xml file and check it into your repository

For example to set up an `android_binary` that depends on Volley using a Maven profile that uses JCenter as the central repository,

```
$ cat WORKSPACE
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:maven_rules.bzl", "maven_aar")
maven_aar(
    name = "volley",
    artifact = "com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0",
    settings = "//:settings.xml",
)

$ cat settings.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'
    xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>bintray</name>
          <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <id>bintray</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>

$ cat BUILD
android_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    custom_package = "com.example.app",
    deps = ["@volley//aar"],
)
```